# Elasticsearch changing multiple aliases with wildcard pattern

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to update the the alias of **multiple** indices that match a pattern?

For example, imagine I have the following indices:

```
test1-a, test2-a, test3-a,
test1-b, test2-b, test3-b
```

with aliases:

```
test1 -> test1-a
test2 - > test2-a
test3 -> test3-a
```

now say I want to change the aliases on all `test*` indices so that the `test*` aliases point to indices `test*-b`

I have been looking in the current documentation, but it seems like there is no supported operation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html

Has anyone been able to perform such an operation with a "wildcard" type query or through a painless / curator script?

Comment: Understood. Removed my answer as it was not answering the question. Interesting challenge but its a very rare scenario. i'll see if i can find anything